# android illegal exception when dialog is showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have crash log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{21f9ba68 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1136,402} not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:402)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:328)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:433)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:416)
at ys.a(ConfirmationDialog.java:82)
at ys.a(ConfirmationDialog.java:76)
at **com.smarttech.kapp.SnapshotActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SnapshotActivity.java:147)**
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3036)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:373)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1222)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:155)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
at android.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:611)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:197)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:9663)
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:7047)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3171)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8876)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1695)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1695)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1695)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1695)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1695)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2671)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1787)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2837)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2549)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4616)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4227)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4303)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4360)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4227)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4227)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4336)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4500)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2607)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2201)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2192)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2584)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

This is soruce code of showing dialog in snapshot activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.snapshot_delete:
            Log.d(TAG, "delete snapshot");
            **delete();**
            return true;
        case R.id.snapshot_share:
            export();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void delete() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Delete snapshot");
    final int index = pager.getCurrentItem();
    ConfirmationDialog.prompt(this, R.string.delete_snapshot, R.string.delete_snapshot_confirmation, R.string.delete, android.R.string.cancel, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            snapshots.get(index).delete();
            loadSnapshots();
        }
    });
}
```

This crash is very hard to reproduce and it is all information what I have.
What is a reason of this exception?
And How it can be fixed?
I think the reason is thread in dialog, but I'm not sure

```
public static void prompt(final Context context, int titleResourceId, int questionResourceId, int positiveButton, int negativeButton, final Runnable confirmedRunnable, final Runnable cancelledRunnable) {
    closeDialog();
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener confirmed = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            currentDialog = null;
            confirmedRunnable.run();
        }
    };
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancelled = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            currentDialog = null;
            if (cancelledRunnable != null) {
                cancelledRunnable.run();
            }
        };
    };
    currentDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle(titleResourceId).setMessage(questionResourceId).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setPositiveButton(positiveButton, confirmed)
            .setNegativeButton(negativeButton, cancelled).show();
    currentDialog.setCancelable(cancelled == null);
    currentDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(cancelled == null);
}
```

This is promt implementation

Comment: The reason behind getting this type of exception is  most probably related to `context`.

Comment: i think ConfirmationDialog.prompt(........) shouid be chanhe to ConfirmationDialog.show(........)

Comment: I added promt implementation

Comment: Why the first line `closeDialog();` in prompt method???

Comment: This method only check if currentdialog != null and dismiss it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The top level of your stacktrace is telling you what is wrong:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{21f9ba68 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1136,402} not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:402)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:328)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:433)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:416)
```

You are calling dismiss on a dialog that is currently not being shown anymore.
As in: your `Activity`/`Fragment` is possibly already destroyed when you call dismiss (-> "not attached to window manager").

[edit] One way to fix this is to check for `activity.isFinishing()` or `fragment.isAdded()`

Comment: can we do like this if(alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()){ alertDialog.dismiss();} ???

Comment: That's probably an even better way.

Answer (score 4):

Please dismiss as follows

```
if ((alertDialog != null) && alertDialog.isShowing())
        {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: even with this check before dismissing, exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to safely dismiss your dialog is to check if the view the Dialog is contained within is currently showing before attempting to dismiss it. This looks like:

```
if (view.isShown()) {
    dialog.dismiss()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why the entire app should crash over something like this. It appears to me that an exception at this point must be the result of the activity already having ended or something. In either case I'm guessing the user isn't looking at the dialog any longer, so I've made simple utility for closing my dialogs silently.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class DialogUtil {

    public static final String TAG = "DialogUtil";

    public static void safeDismiss(Dialog dialog) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                Log.e(TAG, sw.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Same Issue,
and I sove this Issue by checking:

```
if (alertDialog  != null && alertDialog .isShowing() && !this.isFinishing())
 {
  alertDialog .dismiss();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you should also check if activity is not null.

```
if (activity != null && progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
```